# Get selected UIControl in a GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

How is it possible to find out which control in a given MATLAB GUI is currently selected by the user?

For example I want to find out which edit box in the GUI is currently focused since I want to exploit the figures `WindowScrollWheelFcn` to allow increasing/decreasing numeric values by scrolling up/down while the relevant input is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `f` be a handle to the GUI figure. Then

```
h = get(f, 'CurrentObject')
```

returns a handle `h` to that figure's current object, which is the one most recently selected *in that figure* (see the [documentation of figure properties](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html) for more information).

(Note that `gco` returns the current object in the current figure. This is not what you want, because the user may have clicked an object in another figure).

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for!